# Attaching Roles to user - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am beginner with laravel and i want to attach roles to the users. This is how i am trying to do it but then i get an error with the syntax.

**RegisterController**

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']) ,

            saveRoles($request->get('role'));



        ]);
```

**User Model**

```
 public function saveRoles($roles)
{
    if(!empty($roles))
    {
        $this->roles()->sync($roles);
    } else {
        $this->roles()->detach();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `role` is an array of role IDs (even if it's empty or there is just one ID), you don't need to use `detach()` or check if the array is empty. So, `RegisterController@create` method should look like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);

    $user->roles()->sync($data['role']);

    return $user;
}
```